# JavaScript ondblclick not working

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to have a text entry box (and *only* the one single text input) be cleared when double clicked.

Here's the HTML

```
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="green" class="control-label green col-md-2">Green:</label>
<div class="col-md-2">
<input type="text" id="green" ondblclick="Clear();" class="form-control"/>
</div>
```

And the JavaScript

```
    function Clear()
    {    
    this.value="";
    }
```

It doesn't seem to be working, does anyone know what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`this` wont work in this case as it is refering to window object instead use `docuement.getElementById`.

```js
function Clear()
    {    
    document.getElementById('green').value="";
      console.log(this);
     // this..value="";
    }
```

```html
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="green" class="control-label green col-md-2">Green:</label>
<div class="col-md-2">
<input type="text" id="green" ondblclick="Clear();" class="form-control"/>
</div>
```

or you can pass element to Clear function like following:

```js
function Clear(element)
    {    
       element.value = "";
    }
```

```html
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="green" class="control-label green col-md-2">Green:</label>
<div class="col-md-2">
<input type="text" id="green" ondblclick="Clear(this);" class="form-control"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code.

HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="green" class="control-label green col-md-2">Green:</label>
<div class="col-md-2">
  <input type="text" id="green" ondblclick="Clear(this);" class="form-control" />
</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
function Clear(x) {
  x.value = "";
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function Clear() {    
    var _green = document.getElementById(this.event.target.id);
    _green.value="";
}
```

In the above code, we have detect the ID of the called function with `this.event.target.id`. After getting the ID, grab the DOM element with `document.getElementById()` and set the value blank.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `this` to the function as a parameter:

```js
  function Clear(that) {
    that.value = "";
  }
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="green" class="control-label green col-md-2">Green:</label>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <input type="text" id="green" ondblclick="Clear(this);" class="form-control" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to make this work without changing anything inside your function you could bind the element like so:

```
... ondblclick="Clear.call(this);" ...
```

Inside `Clear()` you will reference the element using `this`.

#### Bonus

You could also pass in the event like so:

```
... ondblclick="Clear.call(this, event);" ...
```

Then, your function would look like this:

```
function Clear(event)
{
   // ...
}
```

#### Alternatively

You could also register the event handler separately:

```
document.getElementById('green').addEventListener('dblclick', Clear);
```